# Android error app crashes + log cat

Tags: java, android

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 16776544 free bytes
```

Thanks for any help :))

Edit:
Problem solved with

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: Please don't deface your questions. If you aren't satisfied with the post, delete it

Comment: Instead of allocating additional memory I'd recommend to look for the cause of the memory leak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks outofmemory error.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 16776544 free bytes
```

use android:largeHeap="true" code in your manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```